# KeyError in Python

Tags: python, html, cgi, traceback, keyerror

This is my code:

```
    print """\
<form method="post">
    Please enter Viewer Type:<br />
<table>
"""

#Viewer Type
print "<tr><td>Viewer Type<select name=""ViewerType"">"
print """\
    <option value="C">Crowd Funding
    <option value="P">Premium
"""
#do it button

print """\
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
"""

print """\
</form>
</body>
<html>
"""

ViewerType=form['ViewerType'].value
```

And, when I serve it to a browser, this is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/nandres/dbsys/mywork/James/mywork/ViewerForm.py", >line 42, in ViewerType=form['ViewerType'].value File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 541, in >**getitem** raise KeyError, key KeyError: 'ViewerType'

And line 42 is the last line of my code.

The error isn't actually affecting functionality, and everything works fine, but I don't really want it popping up. Any advice/insight would be appreciated.

Btw, I have this at the top of my code:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script is first called to render the page, the `form` dict is empty. The dict will only get filled when the user actually submits the form. So changing your HTML to

```html
<option value="C" selected>Crowd Funding
```

**won't** help.

So you need to test the dict before you attempt to access it. Eg,

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'

print "<html><body>"
print """\
<form method="post">
    Please enter Viewer Type:<br />
<table>
"""

#Viewer Type
print "<tr><td>Viewer Type<select name=""ViewerType"">"

print """\
    <option value="C">Crowd Funding
    <option value="P">Premium
"""
#do it button

print """\
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
"""

print "</table></form>"

if len(form) > 0:
    ViewerType = form['ViewerType'].value
    print '<p>Viewer Type=' + ViewerType + '</p>'
else:
    print '<p>No Viewer Type selected yet</p>'

print "</body></html>"
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I used your code for inspiration and got it working.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the points. PS. I hope your actual program is not serving HTML with missing closing tags, etc.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution if you don't want it popping:

```
try:
    ViewerType=form['ViewerType'].value
except KeyError:
    pass
```

It'll work but I would recommend you to debug your code and find out why you are getting KeyError. From https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError,

```
Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.
```